# poi.jar workbook.write does not generate excel file

Tags: excel, spring-mvc, apache-poi

I am using poi.jar to generate excel sheet. Sometimes it does not generate the excel sheet and displays special characters in the browser.

When I generate 13 rows then it generates the excel file. But anything more than 13 rows does not generate the file.
  Please help.

I am using spring following controller method to generate excel sheet.

```
      @RequestMapping(value={"/downloadExcel"},method=RequestMethod.GET)
/*public void downloadExcel(@RequestParam(value="excelData", required=true) String excelData,
        HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request) { */
    public void downloadExcel(
            HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request) { 
    Workbook wb=(Workbook)request.getSession().getAttribute("excelData");
     try {

        wb.write(response.getOutputStream());
         response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");                
         response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + "myexcl.xls" + "\"");

     }catch(IOException e)
     {
          Log.error("error building excel sheet "+e.getMessage())   ;
     }         


}
```

Comment: Where's the code that generates the Workbook?

Comment: I found the issue. I should call following code after i set header and content.   wb.write(response.getOutputStream());